# How to handle `AccessDenied` with Spring Boot 3.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, error-handling

I was referring to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptions) article. But in Spring Boot 3.1.4 most of the methods are deprecated or unavailable.

I want to give a custom error response when the access is denied. At the moment, I am redirecting all errors to `/error` using a custom `ErrorController`

```
@RestController
public class ErrorControllerImpl implements ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public ResponseEntity<GeneralResponse> handleError(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                                       final HttpServletResponse response) {

        HttpStatusCode httpStatus = response.getStatus() == 0 ? HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST : HttpStatusCode.valueOf(response.getStatus());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new GeneralResponse("Error from filter"), httpStatus);
    }
}

    @RequestMapping("/error/access-denied")
    public ResponseEntity<GeneralResponse> handleAccessDenied(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                                              final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(new GeneralResponse("Access denied hwo "), HttpStatus.GONE);
    }
```

I would like to have all `AccessDenied` scenarios to be managed by `handleAccessDenied()` method. For now, everything is treated at `/error` and I get `Error from filter` for all error types.

I tired to create a custom implementation of `org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler` and use it with `.exceptionHandling()`. But it didn't work.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                        customizer -> customizer
                                .requestMatchers("/error/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/eod")
                                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                               .....
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                ).exceptionHandling(x -> x.accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())

                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                ).authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(customizer -> customizer
                        .logoutUrl("/api/v1/users/signout")
                        .permitAll()
                        .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                );
    return http.build();
}
```

Basically, I want to properly handle scenarios during filtering. I couldn't find any good resource for the new version of Spring Boot. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptions) article has everything I want, but I am not able to find those handlers. I am confused and drained. Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

Here is my implementation for `AccessDeniedHandler`

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException exc) throws IOException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/error/access-denied");
    }

}
```

In `SecurityConfiguration.java`;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private final CustomAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      // shared this portion already
```

Comment: You are aware that using JWTs the way you are is discourage and that is why there is no implementation for it in spring security. Because jwts should not be used as sessions with browsers.

Comment: Do you have something like this  `server.servlet.context-path="/api"` in you application properties file ?

Comment: If you are starting with spring security i encourage you to read the spring security documentation first, instead of just randomly googling a tutorial that teaches bad practices. If you want to learn more about security, you should do research, you can google why jwts should not be used as sessions.

Comment: if you wish to learn spring security, and i encourage you to do, you should first read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html which will explain how spring security works and also there is part there how spring security handles all exceptions. Then you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html which will explain how spring security handles authentication. If you understand this, then you will mostly understand all the other documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,CustomAccessDeniedHandler customAccessDeniedHandler) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            customizer -> customizer.requestMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/eod").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .exceptionHandling(x -> x.accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler).authenticationEntryPoint(customAccessDeniedHandler))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    return http.build();
}

 @Component
 static class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler,AuthenticationEntryPoint {
     @Override
     public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
         response.sendRedirect("/error/access-denied");
     }
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException exc) throws IOException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/error/access-denied");
    }
}
```